# Where is Airflow Docker store temp files?

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm testing with the Airflow Docker,  I have a job that write data to a local folder, such as "/tmp".  It looks that the writing was good, but I just couldn't find the file.  I logged into some of the containers, but couldn't find the file anywhere.  Anyone knows where it is?

Thank you for your help!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have mentioned "containers", so I assume you are not running in `standalone` mode (in which case there will be only one container). So can you add your docker-compose file or docker commands to the question? Personally, I found standalone mode simple for local testing, for which the compose file looks like [this](https://github.com/devatherock/random-demo/blob/airflow/docker-compose.yml) and a simple dag that writes a file to a host folder named `out` looks like [this](https://github.com/devatherock/random-demo/blob/airflow/airflow/dags/file_jobs.py)